# python check if a string is printable

Tags: python, string

I want to know if a certain string is printable. The first way to do this that i found was this code:

```
def is_printable(string):
     try:
         print(string)
         return(True)
     except UnicodeEncodeError:
         return(False)
```

but, I have to test a few thousands strings and I don't want to flood my screen with thoses strings.
So after a quick search on google, I found the `isprintable()` method but if I do this:

```
for string in words:
    if string.isprintable():
        print(string)
```

I still get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: character maps to <undefined>
```

which, as far as I understand, tell me that the string can't be printed, but I just checked that the same string was printable with the `isprintable()` method.

So if anyone know how to check if a string is printable without actually printing anything, please tell me.

Comment: First of all, you're overriding python's `string` class with your variable name. Choose another name. Second of all, it seems you simply defined a function outside of a class context, and then you're trying to call `string.isprintable()` instead of `isprintable(string)`

Comment: Why haven't you redirected output to `/dev/null`?

Comment: @Itay Pythons string class is called `str` not `string`. Using `string` as an identifier - though not very readable - is very much safe

Comment: @rdas You are right, but there's still a python module called [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes you're right, this works fine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found how to do this:

```
import os
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout

f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stdout = f                           # redirect the stdout to os.devnull to "hide" it

printable_words = []
for word in words:
    try:
        print(word)
        printable_words.append(word)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        pass
sys.stdout = old_stdout                  # reset the stdout to see what i will print later
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    print("will not print")
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer right now - but it's missing an explanation/links to the docs.

Comment: yes but the issue with this is that as you redirect the output, the try/except don't work anymore because it can't access the error which is redirected.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some links to the python documentation that might help:

[`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable)

[`str.isprintable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isprintable)

You should be able to do

```
if string.printable:
    print(string)
```

or

```
if str.isprintable():
    print(str)
```

Comment: to quote the docs for isprintable(), "It has no bearing on the handling of strings written to sys.stdout or sys.stderr.)" so this can't help me and the printable attribute don't seems to work in python 3.8+